# How to find the same elements in tow arrays of two different tables in HIVE?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have two tables like the follows:

table1:

```
id               sid
1   |   ['101', '102', '103']
2   |   ['102', '101', '103']
3   |   ['103', '101', '102']
```

table2:

```
id  |            sid
1   |   ['101', '102', '103']
3   |   ['102', '103']
```

and I wish to get the following table:

```
id               sid
1   |   ['101', '102', '103']
2   |   ['102', '101', '103']
3   |   ['103', '102']
```

Explanation： I wish to select the same elements in table1.sid and table2.sid with the same order in table1. Besides, if the id in table1 doesn't exist in table2, then keep the sid as it is in table1. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `posexplode()` to basically do what you want.  Of course, all this array stuff is more complex in Hive than in other databases, particularly getting the results in the order you want:

```
select t1.id, collect_list(sid2)
from (select t1.id, t2.sid2, t1.pos1
      from (table1 t1 lateral view
            posexplode(t1.sid) as pos1, sid1
           ) left join
           (table2 t2 lateral view
            posexplode(t2.sid) as pos2, sid2
           )
           on t2.id = t1.id and t2.sid2 = t1.sid1
      distribute by t1.id
      order by t1.id, t1.pos1
     ) t
```

Something like this:

with t as (
      select t1.id, collect_list(sid2) as sid
      from (select t1.id, t2.sid2, t1.pos1
            from (table1 t1 lateral view
                  posexplode(t1.sid) as pos1, sid1
                 ) left join
                 (table2 t2 lateral view
                  posexplode(t2.sid) as pos2, sid2
                 )
                 on t2.id = t1.id and t2.sid2 = t1.sid1
            distribute by t1.id
            order by t1.id, t1.pos1
           ) t
    select t1.id,
           (case when size(t.sid) = 0 then t1.sid else t.sid end)
    from t1 left join
         t
         on t1.id = t.id